# Can someone please explain why is the RegExp.test behaving in such a way?

Tags: javascript, node.js

> NOTE: I faced this issue in real life production application. Though I was able to resolve it, sadly, I don't understand why its behaving like this.

I have this regular expression

```js
// Notice global modified at the end.
const regexExp = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T((\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))\.(\d{3})Z/g;

// Array of same string 6 times.
[
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
]
.forEach((i) => console.log(regexExp.test(i)));

    // This would print
    // true
    // true
    // false -> Why?
    // true
    // true
    // false -> why?
```

You can run the code by clicking `Run Code snippet`.
I am baffled as why is it testing `false` every `3rd` time?

Following two solutions tend to work.

1. `Defining the Expression inside the forEach block.`

```js
// Array of same string 6 times.
[
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
]
.forEach((i) => {
  const regexExp = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T((\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))\.(\d{3})Z/g;
  console.log(regexExp.test(i))
});

    // This would print
    // true
    // true
    // true -> Yay!!
    // true
    // true
    // true -> Yay!!
```

I know why this works, as basically for each block scope, new regex is created. i.e. for each loop, a new regex is created and hence same object is never used for second call.

Method 2: `Use i modifier instead of g modified`

```js
// Notice global modified at the end.
const regexExp = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T((\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}))\.(\d{3})Z/i;

// Array of same string 6 times.
[
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
  '{"ApplicationDate.Time.DateTime":{"$gte":"2017-08-14T11:27:26.034Z","$lt":"2017-08-24T11:27:26.034Z"}}',
]
.forEach((i) => console.log(regexExp.test(i)));

    // This would print
    // true
    // true
    // true -> Yay!!
    // true
    // true
    // true -> Yay!!
```

So why is this happening,

1. why is Method 2 working?
2. Why it works when I use `i` modifier and why it does not work with `g` modifier?
3. Why every `3rd` test? Why not `4th` or `5th` or `any random` test?

It seems that when using `g` modifier mutates the `RegExp` instance, why is that so?

I would really appreciate if someone can shed some light on this question.

Thanks in advance.